# How do I spread out temperatures in the same year for ggplot2?

Tags: r, temperature

I've got monthly temp data that spans over 16 years. I've formatted it like this in excel:

| date | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 2002-1-1 | 4.38 |
| 2002-1-2 | 2.88 |
| 2002-1-3 | 3.06 |
| 2002-1-4 | 5.53 |
| 2002-1-5 | 7.47 |
| 2002-1-6 | 10.62 |
| 2002-1-7 | 14.11 |
| 2002-1-8 | 15.82 |
| 2002-1-9 | 14.9 |
| 2002-1-10 | 12.81 |
| 2002-1-11 | 9.02 |
| 2002-1-12 | 5.51 |

This is the code in R I have so far:

```
dput(all_temp_data)

all_temp <- ggplot(data = all_temp_data, x = date, y = temperature)

all_temp + geom_point(aes(x = date, y = temperature)) + geom_line(aes(x = date, y = temperature))
```

However the dates don't descend in terms of the month and year, just by the year to give a graph that looks like:

[image]

How do I change it to descend in month and years?

Comment: please add sample data using the output of `dput(all_temp_data)`

Comment: I'm so sorry I'm new to this and I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: you edit a copy_paste the output of the above mentioned command into a code-block in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample data provided: You should (probably) convert your dates to a real date format, using `as.Date()`.

based on your sample data, try:

```
library(tidyverse)
all_temp_data %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%d-%m")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = temperature)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

**sample data used**

```
all_temp_data <- read.table(text = "date    temperature
2002-1-1    4.38
2002-1-2    2.88
2002-1-3    3.06
2002-1-4    5.53
2002-1-5    7.47
2002-1-6    10.62
2002-1-7    14.11
2002-1-8    15.82
2002-1-9    14.9
2002-1-10   12.81
2002-1-11   9.02
2002-1-12   5.51", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: It's still coming up with all the months on one vertical line. Should I input more of my data?

Comment: just edit the `dput()` of your sample data into your question.